# I'm trying to echo data from DB using MySql and php

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I'm trying to echo data from DB but it is showing 500 error. Same code works in some other server but it is not working in my present diff server.

```
  <?php 
    error_reporting(0); 
    session_start(); 
    $hostname_dbConn = "localhost";
    $database_dbConn = "data_data"; 
    $username_dbConn = "user_data"; 
    $password_dbConn = "datauser"; 
    $dbConn = mysql_pconnect($hostname_dbConn, $username_dbConn, $password_dbConn) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); mysql_select_db($database_dbConn, $dbConn);  
    $query_getconfig = "SELECT * FROM configuration WHERE status = 'A'"; 
    $getconfig = mysql_query($query_getconfig, $dbConn) or die(mysql_error()); 
    $row_getconfig = mysql_fetch_assoc($getconfig); $totalRows_getconfig = mysql_num_rows($getconfig); 
?>
```

Comment: <?php session_start();  $hostname_dbConn = "localhost"; $database_dbConn = "data_investordairy"; $username_dbConn = "user_investordai"; $password_dbConn = "Deekonda1"; $dbConn = mysql_pconnect($hostname_dbConn, $username_dbConn, $password_dbConn) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); mysql_select_db($database_dbConn, $dbConn); $query_getconfig = "SELECT * FROM configuration WHERE status = 'A'"; $getconfig = mysql_query($query_getconfig, $dbConn) or die(mysql_error()); $row_getconfig = mysql_fetch_assoc($getconfig);
$totalRows_getconfig = mysql_num_rows($getconfig); ?>

Comment: Please add more information about your problem: what is the SQL query you use to echo your data, what is your echoing script, add the error message that accompanies your 500 error if that is also printed. And if possible, explain to us what you think is different on this server (the one with the error) from the server on which your script is working.

Comment: please check above code. It is working in one server but not working in the diff server.

Comment: You should check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php as using `mysql_` is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `error_reporting(0);` and check what errors exactly are you facing?

```
Either @mysql_pconnect($hostname_explorecalirfornia, $username_explorecalirfornia, $password_explorecalirfornia) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);  //@ infront of mysql_pconnect or use below written code

    $mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DBNAME);
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
     }
```

For fetch record.

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM configuration WHERE status = 'A'";
// get the result object.
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
// fetch the result row.
$data = $result->fetch_assoc();

return $data;
```

with mysqli

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="SELECT Lastname,Age FROM Persons ORDER BY Lastname";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

// Numeric array
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
printf ("%s (%s)\n",$row[0],$row[1]);

// Associative array
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
printf ("%s (%s)\n",$row["Lastname"],$row["Age"]);

// Free result set
mysqli_free_result($result);

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: This page isn’t working www.exmaple.in is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: It is not establishing the connection also

Comment: The connection is established when we use mysqli_connect instead of mysql_pconnect but the remaining SQL script is not working.

Comment: $dbConn = mysqli_connect("localhost","user_user","password","data_data");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  
connection is established using the above code.
let me know please what is the code for fetch records

Comment: check last edited answer. select and upvot if helped

Comment: What is `Either @mysql_pconnect`?